# Is there a way to detect exisiting link from a text file in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-requests

I have code in jupyter notebook with the help of requests to get confirmation on whether that url existed or not and after that prints out the output into the text file. Here is the line code for that

```
import requests

Instaurl = open("dictionaries/insta.txt", 'w', encoding="utf-8")

cli = ['duolingo', 'ryanair', 'mcguinness.paddy', 'duolingodeutschland', 'duolingobrasil']
exist=[]
url = []

for i in cli:
  r = requests.get("https://www.instagram.com/"+i+"/")
  if r.apparent_encoding == 'Windows-1252':
    exist.append(i)
    url.append("instagram.com/"+i+"/")
    Instaurl.write(url)
```

Let's say that inside the cli list, i accidentally added the same existing username as before into the text file (duolingo for example). Is there a way where if the requests found the same URL from the text file, it would not be added into the the text file again?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You defined a list:

```
cli = ['duolingo', ...]
```

It sounds like you would prefer to define a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
cli = {'duolingo', ...}
```

That way, duplicates will be suppressed.
It happens for dups in the initial
assignment, and for any duplicate `cli.add(entry)` you might attempt later.

Comment: btw the actual cli is an output from an insta name generator, the cli above was just an example. If I were to dismiss the duplication, do I need to change it from this [] to this {}? since i made the output prints out into a list instead of a set @J_H

Comment: [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Your current datastructure is a list. I explained that you'd be better off if it were a set. You can use {a, b, c} syntax for initial assignment, or as I explained you can repeatedly do `cli.add(a);` `cli.add(b);` `cli.add(c)`, which would produce the same effect.